# Calling function before objects are created in a class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, dependencies

Basically, I have one class that owns another object:

```
class A()
{
    A() { initSystems() };
    void initSystems();
    B b;
}

class B()
{
    B() { //Does stuff that requires 'initSystems()' to be called before }
}
```

and for 'B' to function, the init systems function needs to be called in A. Is there any 'nice' way to work around this? Like creating the 'B' object later or something?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like your classes are too [tightly coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). There's many ways to fix this, but it depends on the rest of your design.

Maybe A shouldn't own a B, since A is a dependency of B. You could [inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) an instance of A into each B as they get instantiated.

Maybe B shouldn't exist and all, and it should be merged into A:

```
class A()
{
    A() {
        initSystems();
        //Does stuff that requires 'initSystems()' to be called before
    }
    void initSystems();
    // B's methods
}
```

It's my opinion that most initialization methods are code smells (that is, it suggests a bad design). Some people have given this pattern a name: ["Design Smell: Temporal Coupling"](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/)

Answer (score 3):

If you desire to keep the B a regular member of A, the two places you can run code before the construction of `b` are:

1. the constructor of a base class of A,
2. in the initializer list of a member of A, for a member declared above `b`.

If you wish to defer construction of the B, you need to hold the object by indirection or later construct it onto raw storage and when destroying, perform placement destruction.

Most of this has strange smells to it, it may be beneficial to reorganize your code to avoid this kind of structure.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, so would it be a good idea to store a pointer to class B in A, (B* b;), then initialise that after I have called initSystems() in the constructor ( b = new b(); ), or should i focus on redesigning my classes? (In reality class A is a 'Game' class which is effectively the first thing that is run, and class B is a renderer class that renderers game objects to the screen )

Comment: @TheInfernalCow If your game is essentially single-instance, you may want to move the glue and hosting responsibility out of it into something aware of both the systems and the nested entities. It seems to be way too responsible as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change your design so `initSystems()` is requirement for both `A` and `B`.

If you can't do this (although you really should), there are other ways, like dynamic allocation:

```
class A()
{
    A() { 
      initSystems(); 
      b = std::make_unique<B>();
    };
    void initSystems();
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @nanny over the decoupling of the class and merging if possible.

But your scenario seems like in which B is separate entity in your system, hence a class. And **A** contains a **B**, hence the composition.

So one way of solving this would be, you keep a reference (pointer) to B in A instead of making B a part of A.

Or you should not access the stuff that is created in initInstance() of A in the constructor of B, and create a method postConstruct in B that you can call from A after call initInstance. Following code explains it,

```
class A()
{
    A()
    { 
        initSystems();
        b.postContruct()
    }
    void initSystems()
    {
        // do the init instance stuff here.
    }
    B b;
}

class B()
{
    B() {}

    void postContruct()
    { 
       //Does stuff that requires 'initSystems()' to be called before 
    }
}
```